# Unable to continually play songs using LibVLCSharp

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlcsharp

I'm adding VLC support for my VoiceAttack (voice recognition) plugin for a flight simulator.
I instantiated a media object and started playing.
The object is stored globally in Globals.vaProxy.SessionState so the user can stop/pause/next etc.
What I am trying to achieve is a continuing play.
I cannot wait for the song to end; this will not enable me to run other commands, so I will add an event:

```
  mediaPlayer.EndReached += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
            mediaPlayer.Play(media);

 private static void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayNextSong();
        }

        private static  void PlayNextSong()
        {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = Globals.vaProxy.SessionState["player"];
            List<Media> playList = Globals.vaProxy.SessionState["playList"];

            if (playList.Count > 0)
            {
                var nextMedia = playList[0];
                playList.RemoveAt(0);
                var state = mediaPlayer.State;//I get to this in the debugger and the stated is "Ended"
                mediaPlayer.Play(nextMedia);//I step through here but no song is played
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Playlist ended.");
                // Perform any necessary actions when the playlist ends

                // Stop the media player and clean up resources
                mediaPlayer.Stop();
                mediaPlayer.Dispose();
                Globals.vaProxy.SessionState["player"] = null;
                Globals.vaProxy.SessionState["playList"] = null;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that no song is played, and no error appears when I reach the code that is supposed to play the song in the triggered function: this one:

```
 var state = mediaPlayer.State;//I get to this in the debugger and the stated is "Ended"
                mediaPlayer.Play(nextMedia);//I step through here but no song is played
```

What is wrong, or how can I achieve continued play without waiting for a song to end but with the ability to still control the object externally?

Thanks